# Can't download zip files from github

Tags: windows-10, github

I have a strange problem i can't download zip file from github

I get "Unable to connect", on my browser (firefox, chrome) however other devices on the same network are able to download files from github. Even worse thing is that from tor browser i can download files.

Using the default windows firewall and defender, tried disabling defender nothing happened same problem.

Tried resting DNS and network settings same problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening the browser in *safe* mode, i.e., with all add-ons disabled? It could be an extension causing the issue. Also, check if the browser complains of invalid certificate -- that issue can be ignored at user discretion.

Comment: Try: (1) Chrome incognito mode (extensions disabled),  (2) Temporarily disabling your firewall and all security software.

Comment: no that doesn't work, i will go further than that. third party software that use git repositories aren't able to download files from it.

Comment: Different internet connection work? Different computer?

Comment: As i mention in the description different devices on the same network, however i have no capability to test this home pc on different network.
I tried using a VPN and sadly same issue i get can't connect to download.

Comment: Just tried running live linux distro and as expected no problem downloading those files.
This is why i call it strange problem, don't have any problem with other servers, even the github software has no problem downloading repos from the site. However third party software and web browsers fail to download files from the git hub page.

Comment: Couldn't figure this issue and reinstalled windows. Now I can download zip files from github